# Java Swing: do I need two threads?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing

I have this method to update value of a TextArea:

```
private void startShow(String fileName, TextArea textArea) throws InterruptedException{
        textArea.setVisible(true);
        int ptr=0;
        String[] tokens=s.split(" ");
        while (ptr<tokens.length){
            try {
                 Thread.sleep(1000+textSpeed*50);          //1000 milliseconds is one second
            } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
                  Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
            textArea.setText(tokens[ptr]);
            ptr++;
        }
    }
```

Here, textSpeed is a class variable that is updated by clicking a button like this:

```
Button button_1 = new Button("+");
button_1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        textSpeed++;
    }
});
```

While my code is in the while loop, the button is unclickable and thus textSpeed cannot change. My question is:

1) Can I make the button clickable without multithreading? I just started Java Swing and I have no previous experience with multithreading so I don't know if there's a simpler solution.

2) If multithreading is necessary, how would I implement that in the above code? Any tips or suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your questions:

> 1) Can I make the button clickable without multithreading? I just started Java Swing and I have no previous experience with multithreading so I don't know if there's a simpler solution.

The direct answer is no, you must use some form of multithreading, **but** you could do your threading **indirectly** by using a [Swing Timer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to do the delays for you. For details, check the tutorial. For your program, you'd likely use the `actualSpeed` to set the delay time of your Timer object.

> 2) If multithreading is necessary, how would I implement that in the above code? Any tips or suggestions would be great. Thanks!

This question is a bit broad, perhaps overly broad, and in this situation, I find that the best answer is for you to read the tutorials. For Swing Threading, check [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html). Then after digesting this information if later you have a more specific question, it will be much more easily answered with a specific answer.